# Programmatically triggering a click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below an example of triggering a click using jQuery:

```
$('#input_element').click();
```

I'm wondering how can I do this in React.js? Are there any best practices?

Comment: This should work because the `.click()` method is just JavaScript code not even jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to achieve this. Using vanilla javascript is enough, but there are many ways you can do this:

#### Vanilla js:

This is probably the preferred way since it's simple and doesn't require additional libraries to be imported (e.g `jQuery` or `React-DOM`).

```
someFunction = () => {
    document.getElementById("input_element").click();
}
```

---

#### jQuery:

If you already have jQuery imported into your project, you could also do:

```
import jQuery from 'jQuery';
...
someFunction = () => {
    jQuery('#input_element').click();
}
```

---

#### Using `ref`:

If you'd rather use a `ref` instead of `id` you can do:

```
import ReactDOM = from 'react-dom';
...
someFunction = () => {
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.input_element).click(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

just put it inside your `componentDidMount` like this:

```
componentDidMount : function () {
    $('#input_element').click();
},
```

Your `componentDidMount` is an equivalent to `document.ready`

Comment: Can I use refs + ReactDOM to achieve the same thing?

Comment: I think refs can be used, though I haven't tried that. Just use it and let me know if it works